Obtaining the inverse of Matrix $A$ with matrix $C$ with its elements as the cofactor of elements of $A$
Here is the proof of a definition of the inverse of a matrix $A$ from Mathematical Methods for physics and engineering (p264) by K. F. RILEY, M. P. HOBSON and S. J. BENCE.
I don't understand what motivates the creation of $A'.$

I understand the final form of (8.56) is the identity matrix as defined by $A^{-1}A = I$ and everything else except the leap from equation (8.57) to the subsequent sentence. I understand how the paragraph after (8.57) can (mathematically and in technicality) produce the two definitions of $|A|$ and $|A'|$ as well as understand how $|A|$ and $|A'|$ can construct (8.57) (as all values where $i \neq j$ is zero and $i=j$ is $|A|$. However I don't understand why or under what logic $A'$ is "created" in the first place.

We want to prove eq.(8.57)
$$\sum_k C_{ki} A_{kj} = |A|\delta_{ij}.$$
To prove this, we consider two possible values of $\delta_{ij}$, so we need to establish two identities:
$$\sum_k C_{ki} A_{ki} = |A|$$
$$\sum_k C_{ki} A_{kj} = 0\quad\text{for $i \neq j$}$$
The first one is just the Laplace expansion of the determinant. And the second one looks very similar to the first (it is sometimes called "false expansion"), so we may try to use Laplace expansion to prove the second one too.
Clearly, we need another matrix to do this. What should this matrix be? It must have the same cofactors $C_{ki}$, but they must be multiplied not by entries $A_{ki}$, but by different entries $A_{kj}$. So we construct a new matrix $A'$ such that all columns except $i$ are the same (this guarantees that the cofactors $C'_{ki} = C_{ki}$ are the same), but the $i$-th column is replaced by the $j$-th, so $A'_{ki} = A_{kj}$. And now we have
$$\sum_k C_{ki} A_{kj} = \sum_k C'_{ki} A'_{ki} = |A'| = 0$$
because the matrix $A'$ has two identical columns.
